# How work the waypoints of the divi theme on wordpress?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

`Divi theme` implements `waypoints`, anyone know how it works and how could use them? for example This class allows animations to at some point `et-waypoint` but I need know how to manipulate the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works like this , When you assign `et-waypoint` class to any divi module , it will be automatically picked up by jQuery written in divi JS,

```
<script>
(function($) {
    var $animation_elements = $('.et-waypoint'),
        $window = $(window);

    function check_if_in_view() {
        var window_height = $window.height(),
            window_top_position = $window.scrollTop(),
            window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

        $animation_elements.each(function() {
            var $element = $(this),
                element_height = $element.outerHeight(),
                element_top_position = $element.offset().top,
                element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

            //check to see if this element is within viewport
            if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) && (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
                $element.addClass('et-animated');
            } else {
                $element.removeClass('et-animated');
            }
        });
    }

    $window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

in this case , `$animation_elements` grabs et-waypoint and it calls `check_if_in_view` on window scroll.